# Alternatives to Windows Azure Pack Web Sites?

Tags: .net, azure

Recently found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/01/19/revisiting-windows-azure-pack-web-sites-v2-support-lifecycle-dates/) article outlining that Windows Azure Pack Web Sites v2 Mainstream support ends on 11th July 2017.

With that news released, I'm curious as to what others may be using in house for internal hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Stack would be the way to go. Azure stack offers you ability to deploy "Azure" on premises. You can read more about it [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/). The only problem with that is - Azure Stack is only sold with hardware. So it won't be cheap.

I don't think Microsoft offers anything apart from Azure Stack. Well, unless you want to just create VM's with IIS on your own.

Comment: Would you happen to know of any alternative outside of Microsoft?

Comment: i don't, but it doesn't mean they don't exist. I'm not a big expert in hosted iis solutions

Answer (score 0):

Increased support depends on Azure Pack being run on Windows Server 2016.

- Mainstream support increased to 1/11/2022
- Extended support increased to 1/12/2027

Detailed info available from Microsoft here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2016/11/14/windows-azure-pack-lifecycle-was-extended-to-2027/
and
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Windows%20Azure%20Pack

Summary in the attached image:
[Azure Pack Updated Support Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7576H.png)

Comment: Please add some context to your answer. Link may expire and content on a linked page may change/disappear/be moved making your answer no longer valid.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback. Post edited as per your recommendation.